# the difference between struct with flexible arrays members and struct with pointer members

Tags: c, flexible-array-member

I'm quit confused with the difference between flexible arrays and pointer as struct members. Someone suggested, struct with pointers need malloc twice. However, consider the following code:

```c
    struct Vector {
        size_t size;
        double *data;
    };
    int len = 20;
    struct Vector* newVector = malloc(sizeof *newVector + len * sizeof*newVector->data);
    printf("%p\n",newVector->data);//print 0x0
    newVector->data =(double*)((char*)newVector + sizeof*newVector);
    // do sth
    free(newVector);
```

I find a difference is that the address of data member of Vector is not defined. The programmer need to convert to "find" the exactly address. However, if defined Vector as:

```c
    struct Vector {
        size_t size;
        double data[];
    };
```

Then the address of data is defined.

I am wondering whether it is safe and able to malloc struct with pointers like this, and what is the exactly reason programmers malloc twice when using struct with pointers.

Comment: One difference: you can have an array of structures with pointers, but you can't have an array of structures with flexible array members.  Of course, to have an array of structures with pointers, you must separate the allocation of the structures from the allocation of the variable length data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is how the struct is stored. In the first example you over-allocate memory but that doesn't magically mean that the `data` pointer gets set to point at that memory. Its value after malloc is in fact indeterminate, so you can't reliably print it.

Sure, you can set that pointer to point beyond the part allocated by the struct itself, but that means potentially slower access since you need to go through the pointer each time. Also you allocate the pointer itself as extra space (and potentially extra padding because of it), whereas in a flexible array member `sizeof` doesn't count the flexible array member. Your first design is overall much more cumbersome than the flexible version, but other than that well-defined.

The reason why people malloc twice when using a struct with pointers could either be that they aren't aware of flexible array members or using C90, or alternatively that the code isn't performance-critical and they just don't care about the overhead caused by fragmented allocation.

Comment: Another potential reason for using a separate malloc for the pointer to the data could be to have equal sized objects to make them usable with `qsort` and similar algorithms.

Comment: The correct term for an array with unspecified size in a structure is “flexible array member,” not “variable length array.”

Comment: good viewpoint @TedLyngmo

Comment: @Lundin Hi, I'm still confusing, In your answer, you said the first example need go through the pointer each time. However, in the VLA case, it still need to go through the VLA member `data`, which is also a pointer. Or I'm not get what go through exactly means?  Thanks

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah yes of course. Shouldn't post before morning coffee. It has been fixed now.

Comment: @amont In the flexible array member ("VLA") case, there is no separate pointer allocated. It gets treated as an array. It's essentially the same thing as having a string either as `char* str = "hello;` or `char str[] = "hello";`, the former allocates a separate pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering whether it is safe and able to malloc struct with pointers like this, and *what is the exactly reason programmers malloc twice when using struct with pointers.*

If you use pointer method and malloc only once, there is one extra thing you need to care of in the calculation: **alignment**.

Let's add one extra field to the structure:

```
struct Vector {
    size_t size;
    uint32_t extra;        
    double *data;
};
```

Let's assume that we are on system where each field is 4 bytes, there is no trailing padding on struct and total size is 12 bytes. Let's also assume that `double` is 8 bytes and requires alignment to 8 bytes.

Now there is a problem: expression `(char*)newVector + sizeof*newVector` no longer gives address that is divisible by 8. There needs to be manual padding of 4 bytes between structure and data. This complicates the malloc size calculation and data pointer offset calculation.

So the main reason you see 1 malloc pointer version less, is that **it is harder to get right**. With pointer and 2 mallocs, or flexible array member, compiler takes care of necessary alignment calculation and padding so you don't have to.

Comment: `sizeof` counts the padding bytes appended by the struct.

Comment: @Lundin What padding are you referring to? There is no padding at the end of struct in my example. User needs to add manual padding between structure and the array.

Comment: Well you didn't mention how large pointers are on your fictional system. In case the the pointer is 4 bytes then indeed that would be problematic in case double requires 8 byte alignment. On a x86_64 however, there will 4 byte padding after the `uint32_t` (but not at the end of the struct) so we end up with 8+8+8 and 8 byte alignment. I suppose something like `_Alignas(double) struct Vector v;` might make the code more portable.